# Scope of jsp:useBean-how to use object in request scope?

Tags: jsp

I'm newbie to jsp,
sorry for the basic question and unclear expression.

why I can't get the Property from the first jsp file what I set by request scope.

but it's ok by session scope.
I thought they were all delivered by the request scope.

Thanks a lot!!

```html
 
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<jsp:useBean id="myBean" class="ch05_04.LotteryBean" scope="session"/>
<!--I had to use the session scope to deliver the property what I set.-->
<!--why i couldn't use request scope-->
<jsp:setProperty name="myBean" property="lowerBound" value="1" />
<jsp:setProperty name="myBean" property="upperBound" value="49" />
<jsp:setProperty name="myBean" property="ballNumber" value="6" />
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><!--This is First.jsp-->
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>查詢名牌(Lab05_04)</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>查詢名牌</h2> 
<Form action="Second.jsp" method="POST"> 
    訪客姓名:<input type="text" name="visitor" size = "10"><P/>
         <input type="submit" value="確定"><P/>
</Form>
</body>
</html>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><!--This is Second.jsp-->
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>報明牌</title>
</head>
<body>
<% request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); %>
<H2>卜籤求明牌</H2>   
${param.visitor}，您好，<BR>  
您的明牌為：
<jsp:useBean id="myBean" class="ch05_04.LotteryBean" scope="session"/>
 <!--I had to use the session scope to accept the property what I set.-->
 <!--why i couldn't use request scope-->
<jsp:getProperty name="myBean" property="luckyNumbers"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unclear. Please tell us what you are doing, what you expect to happen, and what happens instead.

Comment: I added the comments in code, 
hoping the comments could complement my poor expression,
thanks a lot!

Comment: If something is stored in the request scope, it stays there only for the current request. Since you have 2 JSPs, each generating a complete HTML page, I guess you use two requests: 1 to display the first page, and one to display the second page.

Comment: thanks a lot!
there are two requests, not only one,
so I have to use session scope.
thanks!